# Accessing properties of classes wrapped with "DelphiInterface"

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a FMX project in C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo that is targeted for Android only.  I am trying to make use of the [Camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) API. I used the **Java2Pas** tool to create the Delphi interfaces and classes that I need, combining them into a single Pascal file which I have added to my C++ project.

Parts of this pascal file look like this:

```pascal
  JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListenerClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{106DB13E-C1B4-4898-B906-0143D97C0075}']
    function onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(JSurfaceTextureparam0 : JSurfaceTexture) : boolean; cdecl;// (Landroid/graphics/SurfaceTexture;)Z A: $401
    procedure onSurfaceTextureAvailable(JSurfaceTextureparam0 : JSurfaceTexture; Integerparam1 : Integer; Integerparam2 : Integer) ; cdecl;// (Landroid/graphics/SurfaceTexture;II)V A: $401
    procedure onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(JSurfaceTextureparam0 : JSurfaceTexture; Integerparam1 : Integer; Integerparam2 : Integer) ; cdecl;// (Landroid/graphics/SurfaceTexture;II)V A: $401
    procedure onSurfaceTextureUpdated(JSurfaceTextureparam0 : JSurfaceTexture) ; cdecl;// (Landroid/graphics/SurfaceTexture;)V A: $401
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/view/TextureView_SurfaceTextureListener')]
  JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener = interface(JObject)
    ['{58A7FBD1-27B9-44AC-B013-F077E1BF5975}']
    function onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(JSurfaceTextureparam0 : JSurfaceTexture) : boolean; cdecl;// (Landroid/graphics/SurfaceTexture;)Z A: $401
    procedure onSurfaceTextureAvailable(JSurfaceTextureparam0 : JSurfaceTexture; Integerparam1 : Integer; Integerparam2 : Integer) ; cdecl;// (Landroid/graphics/SurfaceTexture;II)V A: $401
    procedure onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(JSurfaceTextureparam0 : JSurfaceTexture; Integerparam1 : Integer; Integerparam2 : Integer) ; cdecl;// (Landroid/graphics/SurfaceTexture;II)V A: $401
    procedure onSurfaceTextureUpdated(JSurfaceTextureparam0 : JSurfaceTexture) ; cdecl;// (Landroid/graphics/SurfaceTexture;)V A: $401
  end;

  TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener = class(TJavaGenericImport<JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListenerClass, JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener>)
  end;
```

The `TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener` interface needs to be used as a callback object, so I added some event handlers to it and changed it to look like this:

```pascal
  TOnSurfaceTextureDestroyed = function(aSurface: JSurfaceTexture): Boolean of object;
  TOnSurfaceTextureUpdated = procedure(aSurface: JSurfaceTexture) of object;
  TOnSurfaceTextureSize = procedure(aSurface: JSurfaceTexture; aWidth:Integer; aHeight: Integer)  of object;

  TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener = class(TJavaGenericImport<JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListenerClass, JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener>)
  protected
    FOnTextureDestroyed: TOnSurfaceTextureDestroyed;
    FOnTextureUpdated: TOnSurfaceTextureUpdated;
    FOnTextureAvailable: TOnSurfaceTextureSize;
    FOnTextureSizeChanged: TOnSurfaceTextureSize;

  public
    function onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(aSurface : JSurfaceTexture) : boolean; cdecl;
    procedure onSurfaceTextureAvailable(aSurface : JSurfaceTexture; aWidth : Integer; aHeight : Integer) ; cdecl;
    procedure onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(aSurface : JSurfaceTexture; aWidth : Integer; aHeight : Integer) ; cdecl;
    procedure onSurfaceTextureUpdated(aSurface : JSurfaceTexture) ; cdecl;

    property OnTextureDestroyed: TOnSurfaceTextureDestroyed read FOnTextureDestroyed write FOnTextureDestroyed;
    property OnTextureUpdated: TOnSurfaceTextureUpdated read FOnTextureUpdated write FOnTextureUpdated;
    property OnTextureAvailable: TOnSurfaceTextureSize read FOnTextureAvailable write FOnTextureAvailable;
    property OnTextureSizeChanged: TOnSurfaceTextureSize read FOnTextureSizeChanged write FOnTextureSizeChanged;
  end;

implementation

{ TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener }

procedure TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(aSurface: JSurfaceTexture; aWidth, aHeight: Integer);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnTextureAvailable) then
    FOnTextureAvailable(aSurface, aWidth, aHeight);
end;

function TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener.onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(aSurface: JSurfaceTexture): boolean;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnTextureDestroyed) then
    Result := FOnTextureDestroyed(aSurface)
  else
    Result := False;
end;

procedure TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener.onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(aSurface: JSurfaceTexture; aWidth, aHeight: Integer);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnTextureSizeChanged) then
    FOnTextureSizeChanged(aSurface, aWidth, aHeight);
end;

procedure TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener.onSurfaceTextureUpdated(aSurface: JSurfaceTexture);
begin
  if Assigned(FOnTextureUpdated) then
    FOnTextureUpdated(aSurface);
end;
```

The IDE created the Header file that looks like this:

```cpp
__interface JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListenerClass;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListenerClass> _di_JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListenerClass;
__interface JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener> _di_JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener;
class DELPHICLASS TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener;

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{106DB13E-C1B4-4898-B906-0143D97C0075}") JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListenerClass  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObjectClass 
{
    virtual bool __cdecl onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture JSurfaceTextureparam0) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl onSurfaceTextureAvailable(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture JSurfaceTextureparam0, int Integerparam1, int Integerparam2) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture JSurfaceTextureparam0, int Integerparam1, int Integerparam2) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl onSurfaceTextureUpdated(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture JSurfaceTextureparam0) = 0 ;
};

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{58A7FBD1-27B9-44AC-B013-F077E1BF5975}") JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObject 
{
    virtual bool __cdecl onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture JSurfaceTextureparam0) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl onSurfaceTextureAvailable(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture JSurfaceTextureparam0, int Integerparam1, int Integerparam2) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture JSurfaceTextureparam0, int Integerparam1, int Integerparam2) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl onSurfaceTextureUpdated(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture JSurfaceTextureparam0) = 0 ;
};

typedef bool __fastcall (__closure *TOnSurfaceTextureDestroyed)(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture aSurface);
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TOnSurfaceTextureUpdated)(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture aSurface);
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TOnSurfaceTextureSize)(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture aSurface, int aWidth, int aHeight);

class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListenerClass,_di_JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener> 
{
    typedef Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListenerClass,_di_JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener>  inherited;

protected:
    TOnSurfaceTextureDestroyed FOnTextureDestroyed;
    TOnSurfaceTextureUpdated FOnTextureUpdated;
    TOnSurfaceTextureSize FOnTextureAvailable;
    TOnSurfaceTextureSize FOnTextureSizeChanged;

public:
    bool __cdecl onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture aSurface);
    void __cdecl onSurfaceTextureAvailable(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture aSurface, int aWidth, int aHeight);
    void __cdecl onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture aSurface, int aWidth, int aHeight);
    void __cdecl onSurfaceTextureUpdated(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JSurfaceTexture aSurface);
    __property TOnSurfaceTextureDestroyed OnTextureDestroyed = {read=FOnTextureDestroyed, write=FOnTextureDestroyed};
    __property TOnSurfaceTextureUpdated OnTextureUpdated = {read=FOnTextureUpdated, write=FOnTextureUpdated};
    __property TOnSurfaceTextureSize OnTextureAvailable = {read=FOnTextureAvailable, write=FOnTextureAvailable};
    __property TOnSurfaceTextureSize OnTextureSizeChanged = {read=FOnTextureSizeChanged, write=FOnTextureSizeChanged};
public:
    /* TObject.Create */ inline __fastcall TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener(void) : Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListenerClass,_di_JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener> () { }
    /* TObject.Destroy */ inline __fastcall virtual ~TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener(void) { }

};
```

Inside my C++ code, I am trying to use it like this:

```cpp
_di_JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener = TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener::JavaClass->init();
SurfaceTextureListener->OnTextureAvailable = SetupCamera;
```

But the compiler gives me an error:

> no member named 'OnTextureAvailable' in 'Androidcamera2::JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener'

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Feel free to use any code that is useful to you from this project:
https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Camera

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error message because the `JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener` interface does not have the `OnTextureAvailable` property.

The idea here is that the `JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener` interface *is* the callback, and you should implement the `JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener` interface in your own object. Then, in your `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` implementation, you call SetupCamera.

Note that you'll have to call `TextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener` and pass an instance of your `JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener` instance in order to register your listener.

Comment: I am creating the **JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener** interface. would it be possible for you tell me how your interface would be different from the one I created?

Comment: you are supposed to create *your own* class that *implements* the `JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener` interface. Do not modify the generated `TJTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener` class.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am assuming you want me to create a class that looks like `class TTVSTextureListener : public TJavaLocal, public JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener` in C++ or `TTVSTextureListener = class(TJavaLocal, JTextureView_SurfaceTextureListener)` in delphi. The problem is the compiler complains the `equals`, `toString` differ from previous declaration and `QueryInterface`, `AddRef`, `Release`, `getClass`, ... has not been implemented.

Comment: @Sam: Yes, that is what I am referring to.  I can't comment on the errors related to `equals()`/`toString()`/`getClass()`, etc without seeing the actual code and error messages, but the errors related to `QueryInterface()`/`AddRef()`/`Release()` are [documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Inheritance_and_Interfaces#IUnknown_and_IInterface).